# How to add content to newsletter in Mailjet API v3 using ASP .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mailjet

I am able to send empty newsletters. But I dont know how to add content to them. Example given by the Mailjet (http://dev.mailjet.com/guides/newsletter-guide/) does not help much. I get 500 Internal Server Error most of the time.

Calling method:

```
NewsLetterHtmlAdd newsLetterAdd = new NewsLetterHtmlAdd
        {
            ID = idNewsletter,
            Data = string.Format("<!DOCTYPE html" +
                                 "<html>" +
                                 "<head>" +
                                 "<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />" +
                                 "<title>Subject</title>" +
                                 "</head>" +
                                 "<body>" +
                                 "<p style='text-align: center'>Sender <a href='mailto:[[EMAIL_TO]]'>[[EMAIL_TO]]</a>, " + "<a href='[[UNSUB_LINK_EN]]'>Unsubscribe here</a>.</p>"
                                 +
                                 "</body>" +
                                 "</html>")
        };
client.NewsLetterHtmlAdd(newsLetterAdd);
```

Method:

```
    public void NewsLetterHtmlAdd(NewsLetterHtmlAdd newsLetterHtmlAdd)
    {
string url = "https://api.mailjet.com/v3/DATA/NewsLetter/"
                     + newsLetterHtmlAdd.ID + "/HTML/text/html/";



        byte[] byteArray = new byte[newsLetterHtmlAdd.Data.Length*sizeof (char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(newsLetterHtmlAdd.Data.ToCharArray(), 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_apiKey, _secretKey);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = "text/html";
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MailJet.Newsletter
{  [DataContract] 
public class NewsLetterHtmlAdd
{

[DataMember(Name = "id")]
public long ID { get; set; }


[DataMember(Name = "data")]
public string Data { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: `I get 500 Internal Server Error` there should always be additional information. If it is a remote service returning the error you should check the http response description and content for additional information. If your application is generating the error, you should be debugging locally that custom errors are prevented from triggering showing the actual exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the method that works for me. I use ServiceStack.

```
    public void NewsLetterHtmlAdd(NewsLetterHtmlAdd newsLetterHtmlAdd)
    {
        string url = "https://api.mailjet.com/v3/DATA/NewsLetter/" + newsLetterHtmlAdd.ID + "/HTML/text/html/";

        url.PostToUrl(newsLetterHtmlAdd.Data, "text/html; charset=utf-8",
              request =>
              {
                  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_apiKey, _secretKey);
                  request.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
              });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are trying to do a GET request on the /DATA/newsletter resource.
What you need to do instead is to make a POST request with the HTML content in the request body.

Comment: So in POST I have to send ID of the newsletter I am attaching this html to and the Html (newsletter content). Or just the Html content.

Comment: The POST request body should only contain the html content. The newsletter ID is part of the URL that you call, i.e. /v3/DATA/NewsLetter/<newsletter-id>/HTML/text:html/LAST

Comment: what does LAST stand for? my current url is:  string url = "https://api.mailjet.com/v3/DATA/NewsLetter/"                        + newsLetterHtmlAdd.ID + "/HTML/text/html/"; and it POSTs but still no content is visible in the emails. (I do include unsubscribe option)